# How handling a list of polymorphic variants?

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml, variant, polymorphism

Let two variant types :

```
type typeA = 
    | A1 
    | A2
;;  

type typeB = 
    | B1 of typeA
    | B2 of typeA
;;
```

and type-checking functions :

```
let isA1 = function A1 -> true | _ -> false;;
let isA2 = function A2 -> true | _ -> false;;   
let isB1 = function B1 e -> true | _ -> false;;
let isB2 = function B2 e -> true | _ -> false;;
```

I'd like to create a list of those functions to check elements of type A or B

as they're of different types, I need polymorphic variants and I get :

```
type filterA =
{
    handleA : typeA -> bool;
};;

type filterB =
{
    handleB : typeB -> bool;
};;

type filterslist = [`FilterA of filterA | `FilterB of filterB] list ;;

let filters1 = [`FilterA { handleA = isA1 }; `FilterB { handleB = isB1 }] ;;
```

So now I want to iterate over filters1 to check the type of the argument
I tried :

```
let exec_filters filters event = List.iter (fun fil -> match fil with `FilterA -> fil.handleA event; ()| `FilterB -> fil.handleB event; () ) filters;;
```

but it's not appreciated :

```
Error: This expression has type [< `FilterA | `FilterB ]
       but an expression was expected of type filterA
```

How can I handle this ?

Comment: "as they're of different types, I need polymorphic variants" -- nope. If you give us the real stuff you're working with, we're better able to help you, but it seems you're creating more work for yourself here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that you're using "type checking predicates" similar to Scheme or instanceOf indicates that there is probably something very wrong with your code.  OCaml is a statically typed language, you should not:

> iterate over filters1 to check the type of the argument I tried

Why are you doing this?  If you are trying to handle multiple types, the way to do it is to use polymorphism.  Polymorphic variants can be helpful for this, but I'm still not convinced that your code isn't just written in a strange way.

Comment: actually, I'm trying to get a kind of runtime "dynamic" pattern-matching, so yeah I want to handle multiple types, with one specific function triggered for each one

Comment: This doesn't really make any sense.  You can't match on types dynamically in OCaml: the language doesn't work like that.  You can match on values of types dynamically, this is just plain old pattern matching, but matching on types isn't something that the OCaml language allows.  Your question still isn't at all clear.

Answer (score 4):

I think your code should read like:

```
let exec_filters filters event =
  List.iter
    (fun fil -> match fil with
      | `FilterA fA -> fA.handleA event; ()
      | `FilterB fB -> fB.handleB event; () )
    filters;;
```

EDIT: However, this won't typecheck, since `event` can't have types `typeA` and `typeB`...

Why not make your initial variants (`typeA` and `typeB`) polymorphic?

What are you trying to do?

Comment: yeah I get the error : ` | `FilterB(fB) -> fB.handleB event; ()
Error: This expression has type typeA but an expression was expected of type typeB `

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
match fil with
`FilterA -> ...
```

You seem to expect that this will change the type of `fil`, but that's not how it works.  The expression with the type `filterA` appears inside the pattern.  You want something more like this:

```
match fil with
`FilterA { handleA = h } -> h event
```

I'm not sure I see the purpose of having your handlers return `bool` if you're going to use `List.iter` to execute them.  This will return `unit`, and the `bool` values are going to be discarded.

**Edit**

There's a deeper typing problem, explained well by Ptival.  So even if you fix your patterns you'll still need to rethink your plan.  One possible thing to do would be to use variants (not necessarily polymorphic variants, by the way) to track the types of the events.

Comment: doesn't compile... : `This expression has type typeA but an expression was expected of type typeB`

Comment: I'd have to see what you compiled.  You wouldn't get this message for the fragment above (I just verified).  I'll expand the code to a whole function, maybe that will clarify.

Comment: the same as above except the last function : 'let exec_filters filters event =
  List.iter
    (fun fil ->
      match fil with
      | `FilterA { handleA = h } -> h event; ()
      | `FilterB { handleB = h } -> h event; ()
    )
    filters;;'